# ionic app show white screen when I start it in background process

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When my ionic app running in the background, so that app is started again, there will be a white screen, the default view to reload, what measures can be quickly display view?

Comment: Consider adding some of your code

Comment: which platform? IOS/Android? What does your affected html file looks like? U have to add in those .

Comment: add what code  (android)